# Silverlight + RIA Services and customing the user/password storage

Tags: silverlight, forms-authentication, wcf-ria-services

Using the **Silverlight Business Application** template in **VS2010** creates a nice default solution with a Silverlight project and an ASP.NET project. It also automatically provides some nice authentication that seems to store usernames/password/etc for newly registered users into your local SQL Server database.

Is it possible to customize the storage mechanism? I already have a data store elsewhere and want to handle the adding/removing etc of details myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. WCF RIA Services is using the default ASP.NET Membership provider. So search on the web on how to modify them (via web.config) to connect to another source and it will be transparent for the SL/WCF RIA Services application.

For instance, I've connected them to the Azure Storage (table) instead of the default ASPNETDB database on this application : http://cloudypizza.cloudapp.net . You can test it by creating your own account on clicking on "login".

I've briefly explained how I've done it here on [my blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/davrous/archive/2009/10/26/cloudy-pizza-une-application-silverlight-3-net-ria-services-indexable-dans-les-nuages.aspx#azuredev) (in French only sorry)

Regards,

David